# er/expand-region not working as previously under Emacs 25.1

Tags: region, clojure

I've got `er/expand-region` behaving very strangely and I don't understand what I did wrong (besides upgrading to Emacs 25.1.50).

If I've got this in an elisp file:

(defun foo (p) (* 2 2) p)

*(that piece of code is just an example)*

and I'm on the asterisk and start doing expand-region I get:

- "*"(OK)
- "* 2 2" (OK)
- "* 2 2)" (WRONG)
- "(* 2 2)" (kinda OK I guess)
- "(* 2 2) p)" (WRONG)
- "(defun foo (p) (* 2 2) p)" (kinda OK I guess)

I've got the exact same problem with Clojure files.

Previously `er/expand-region` used to select things in between matching parenthesis. The problem is that now I need more keypresses to select what I want and I keep ending up with unbalanced elisp / Clojure code because I cut/kill non-balanced pieces of code.

I tried both calling er/expand-region using the shortcut or calling it manually: same result. From my testing it looks like, say, when in Clojure the `clojure-mode-expansion` list is used etc.

I'm not familiar at all with how `er/expand-region` works internally but it's as if something was called before `er/mark-inside-pairs` and `er/mark-outside-pairs` and that that thing was matching the right parenthesis.

Any idea as to what went wrong and how I could fix this?

I tried both my old er/expand-region and the latest ELPA one.

Comment: I am on the latest version of emacs-25 dev branch but I cannot replicate what you are seeing; my expansion proceeds in this order: "\*", "* 2 2", "(* 2 2)", "defun foo (p) (* 2 2) p", "(defun foo (p) (* 2 2) p)".

Comment: @Kaushal Modi: thank you very much for trying, it's exactly how it behaved for me previously (I was on Emacs 25.0.50, not 25.1.50 previously). I'll keep trying to make it work: I have not idea what went wrong. I'll delete / re-install and try several versions (I'll see what I kind find on melpa, melpa-stable, try with my old Emacs [which I still have working in another user directory], etc.).

Comment: @Kaushal Modi: actually I love expand-region and I'm so used to it working in the way/order you described that I keep making mistakes now that it's doing "weird non balanced expands" :-/

Comment: First try it in an `emacs -Q` session .. In that session, load just this one package and see if you can recreate the same problem with `er/expand-region`. Most likely it will work fine and then you would need to bisect your init.el to find the culprit.

Comment: Are you using the latest expand-region version from MELPA?

Comment: @lunaryom: I eventually solved it although I'm not sure what I did to make it work because I deleted / re-installed many things many times. All I know for sure is I deleted my entire *$HOME/.emacs.d/elpa/* directory and re-installed all my ELPA packages. I can now see I'm using *expand-region 20150902.558* (on Emacs 25.1.50 compiled from sources) and everything works fine again but I don't know if came from MELPA or MELPA-stable. Thanks to you guys for the help: I got it working!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to some breaking changes in Emacs 25.0.*

https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/issues/160

I'm still running 25.0.* and solved the problem by installing `expand-region` from MELPA where a fix to workaround Emacs versions 25+ has been implemented.

Note: Do not use the version (0.10.0) in MELPA **stable** since it does not work.

Comment: I am using the latest version of `expand-region` form Melpa and latest build of emacs from its `emacs-25` branch as of today (25.0.93.x)  and things are working fine as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The latest official Emacs release is 24.5, and the developer of expand-region is [not supporting development versions](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/issues/186) (i.e., 25+). This is not unreasonable, as there are frequent changes in the Emacs 25 branch that break and un-break `expand-region`, such as demonstrated in the question here. Keeping up with them would be a big job for little benefit.

Solutions to the problem:

- stick to an official Emacs release (i.e., 24.5)
- if you use a development version of Emacs, stick to a specific release that works with expand-region. Test builds of new versions before you replace your old versions

Comment: I am using the latest version of `expand-region` form Melpa and latest build of emacs from its `emacs-25` branch as of today (25.0.93.x)  and things are working fine as expected.